# How to send Ajax data to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a value of select to the same page, because there are two selects depends on each other .  I tried all the suggestion solution, but they didn't work

Jquery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Group').change(function(){
            var group_id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:"doc.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{group_id:group_id}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

php code to check if there's a value

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['group_id']))
  echo $_POST['group_id'];
else
  echo 'nooooooooo';
?>
```

but I always get nothing.

The `var group_id = $(this).val();`  get the select value successfully, but ajax doesn't send it to the same page for some reason!

Comment: add ajax success method to fetch server reponse and set that to other selectbox options usinh .html()

Comment: *"but I always get nothing"* ... based on what? You have no success or error handlers in your ajax. We don't know what *"same page"* means either ... is it `doc.php`? Please provide [mcve] and properly detailed problem description as well as troubleshooting steps taken and any relevant errors

Comment: I added the success data, and it return the HTMl code in the page,  and it return nothing because the if isset  doesn't work!

Comment: There is no `isset()` shown. You need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40330274/edit) your question with all relevant details

Comment: Shouldn't 'method' be 'type'?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? with this code, I do not see the necessity to use _ajax_. you are returning the same parameter you are sending to the _doc.php_ file. then why use _ajax_ ? just use `group_id` variable in your _javascript_

Comment: I'm trying to make dependent select.  I mean 2 selects depend on each other, I have to do that using ajax  to avoid refreshing the page

Comment: So what you see in inspector? any errors?